# Why is this struct literal getting corrupted when passed by address in VS2013 but not gcc/clang?

Tags: c, struct, visual-studio-2013, access-violation

I'm putting together a Visual Studio 2013 solution for [a library I maintain](https://github.com/UpstandingHackers/hammer). The library primarily uses arena allocation, so we have an allocator interface:

### allocator.h

```
#define HAMMER_ALLOCATOR__H__
#include <sys/types.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef struct HAllocator_ {
    void* (*alloc)(struct HAllocator_* allocator, size_t size);
    void* (*realloc)(struct HAllocator_* allocator, void* ptr, size_t size);
    void (*free)(struct HAllocator_* allocator, void* ptr);
} HAllocator;
[... API functions ... ]
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

We also implement a wrapper around `malloc`, `realloc` and `free`:

### system_allocator.c

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include "internal.h"

void* system_alloc(HAllocator *allocator, size_t size) { 
    void* ptr = malloc(size + sizeof(size_t));
    *(size_t*)ptr = size;
    return (uint8_t*)ptr + sizeof(size_t);
}

void* system_realloc(HAllocator *allocator, void* ptr, size_t size) {
    if (ptr == NULL)
        return system_alloc(allocator, size);
    ptr = realloc((uint8_t*)ptr - sizeof(size_t), size + sizeof(size_t));
    *(size_t*)ptr = size;
    return (uint8_t*)ptr + sizeof(size_t);
}

void system_free(HAllocator *allocator, void* ptr) {
    if (ptr != NULL)
        free((uint8_t*)ptr - sizeof(size_t));
}

HAllocator system_allocator = {
    .alloc = &system_alloc,
    .realloc = &system_realloc,
    .free = &system_free,
};
```

The `system_allocator` global is declared as `extern` in `internal.h` (which `#include`s `allocator.h`), and it is exported as a symbol (in the .def file). However, apparently the struct is never initialized, because when my unit tests try to pass `system_allocator` by address to a function that dereferences the `alloc` member, they segfault with "Unhandled exception at 0x000007FEFAD3EB6D (hammer.dll) in hammer-test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF."

Inspecting the passed-in pointer in the debugger suggests that something is definitely not right:

- mm__  0x000000013fb0a094 {hammer-test.exe!HAllocator_ system_allocator} {alloc=0x25ff00019ff625ff realloc=...}    HAllocator_ *

  - alloc 0x25ff00019ff625ff  void * (HAllocator_ *, unsigned __int64) *
  - realloc   0x9ffa25ff00019ff8  void * (HAllocator_ *, void *, unsigned __int64) *
  - free  0x00019ffc25ff0001  void (HAllocator_ *, void *) *

Particularly since, when I inspect the original struct literal, everything looks reasonable:

- system_allocator = {alloc=0x000007fefad31410 {hammer.dll!system_alloc} realloc=0x000007fefad313f7 {hammer.dll!system_realloc} ...}

  - alloc = 0x000007fefad31410 {hammer.dll!system_alloc}
  - realloc = 0x000007fefad313f7 {hammer.dll!system_realloc}
  - free = 0x000007fefad310d2 {hammer.dll!system_free}

I tried putting breakpoints on both the declaration and definition of `system_allocator`, and VS2013 informs me that "no executable code of the debugger's target code type is associated with this line." Does that imply that `system_allocator` isn't actually being initialised? (If so, then what do those 0x000007fefad31... addresses mean?)

I've never encountered this problem with gcc or clang, and this is my first time using VS. What am I missing?

EDIT: per chux's comment, the test which is failing is actually failing in setup. system_allocator gets passed like this:

```
HBitWriter *w = h_bit_writer_new(&system_allocator);
```

The line of code that's failing is the first line of `HBitWriter *h_bit_writer_new(HAllocator* mm__)`:

```
HBitWriter *writer = h_new(HBitWriter, 1);
```

where `h_new` is #defined as

```
#define h_new(type, count) ((type*)(mm__->alloc(mm__, sizeof(type)*(count))))
```

Comment: This is an interesting question, I hope you get an answer. It compile ok? No warnings?

Comment: There are some size conversion warnings, but that's it, and none of them are related to the allocator.

Comment: Pedantic suggestion: `return (char*)ptr + sizeof(size_t);`.

Comment: `system_realloc( x, y, 0)` works differently than  `system_free(x,y)`.  May also want to review `system_alloc(x, 0)`.

Comment: Suggest posting code for "when my unit tests try to pass system_allocator".

Comment: Posted; I can add surrounding context if necessary, but the only thing that precedes the call to `h_bit_writer_new` is two local variable declarations.

Comment: Globals go either directly into the .data-section or into its virtual space, so there is no code associated you could debug. As `system_allocator` is initialized, its values exist hardcoded somewhere in the .data-section. There are also relocs associated with it since it contains addresses. However, your second dump suggests that `system_allocater` is already correct, so you should probably next set a bp on `HBitWriter *w = h_bit_writer_new(&system_allocator);` and step through the emitted asm code to verify the correctness of the addresses passed around and the values they contain.

Comment: Are you creating a .dll out of the library ? Wouldn't you need the [dllexport/dllimport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da6zd0a4.aspx) attributes on the functions (and function pointers) of the API ?

Comment: I'm quite surprised the code even compiles on VS2013, the `.alloc = ` syntax is C99 which isn't supported on MSVC++ (which really is a C++ compiler; its C mode is essentially a C++ subset and thus mostly C89)

Answer (score 0):

I bet it is DLL related.  You might have to put together the system_allocater member in the executable instead of passing a structure from the DLL containing the function addresses as the DLL sees them.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Nope. Win32 addresses are valid process-wide and DLLs are loaded in-process.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with breakpoints is fairly easily explained. The Visual C++ debugger works by putting breakpoints in functions. You're trying to put a breakpoint outside a function. That's not supported.

At machine code level, global initializers are run before `main` in an executable, and from `DllMain` in case of a DLL. You've probably commented out the actual initializers for MSVC++, as the code is not valid C++. Yes, I know the question is tagged C, but MSVC++ doesn't support modern C.